# Python - Tkinter - Scrollbar automatically moves when resizing window from corner

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm having a bizarre issue with the code below. If a user runs this code, and the very first thing they do (before even clicking in the window) is resize the window by the bottom-right corner, the scrollbar will automatically move down, instead of staying in place as you'd normally expect.

```
import tkinter as tk


def onResize(event):
    """Prints the scrollbar's position on window resize."""
    print(str(myScrollbar.get()))


root = tk.Tk()
myFrame = tk.Frame(root)
mySecondaryFrame = tk.Frame(root)
myCanvas = tk.Canvas(myFrame)
myScrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(myFrame, orient='vertical', command=myCanvas.yview)

myCanvas.config(yscrollcommand=myScrollbar.set)

for i in range(0,100):
    print(i)
    button = tk.Button(mySecondaryFrame, text=i)
    button.pack(fill='y',expand=True)
    myCanvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 0, 3000))

myFrame.pack(fill='both',expand=True)
myScrollbar.pack(side="right",fill='y')
myCanvas.pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=True)

button_window = myCanvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=mySecondaryFrame)

myCanvas.bind('<Configure>', onResize)

tk.mainloop()
```

In the time I've spent on here looking for a solution to this without having to make a post, I came across the .get() method for scrollbars, and wondered if this would help me pinpoint the issue, hence its place in the code. Strangely enough, when the glitch occurs, I noticed from the print statements that the scrollbar is making tiny horizontal movements. Why is that, considering that the scrollbar is set to the canvas' y view? I'm not sure if this is a case of correlation != causation, but I thought it would be worth mentioning. Any help that could be given would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. When I run the code and immediately resize the window, the scrollbar behaves exactly like I would expect.

Comment: Hmm, that's very strange...may I ask what OS you're on? Perhaps that has something to do with it. I'm on MacOS Sierra. (by the way, it's cool to see your name pop up, Bryan - I've looked at a ton of your responses to other Tkinter-related issues while I've been building my program, haha!)

Comment: Windows 7 behaves correctly for me as well.

Comment: I tried it on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing - the comment section prompted me to test this issue on Mac's Notes system - the same exact thing happens there. Seems it's just an oddity of Mac's scrollbar system, which Tkinter pulled its scrollbar from. Thanks to the users above! Hopefully this question can help anyone else who finds this behavior odd in the future.